# Шаринг файла до его загрузки | JS

Tags: javascript, webapi

Можно ли как-то расшарить файл до его загрузки? navigator.share требует от меня файл в формате File, но у меня есть только ссылка. Получается, что мне приходится грузить весь файл, прежде чем расшарить. Это создает проблему, при которой я могу ждать несколько минут (пока файл не загрузится), прежде чем всплывет окно шаринга.

```
const url = "http://.../item.png";

fetch(url , { mode: 'no-cors' }) .then((r) => r.blob())
                                    .then(function (blob) {
                                        const file = new File([blob], items[opened].filename, {type: items[opened].mime_type});
                                        const filesArray = [file];

                                    if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare({files: filesArray})) {
                                        navigator.share({
                                            files: filesArray
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: `navigator.share требует от меня файл в формате Blob` -- неправда, почитай [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#parameters), там написаны доступные значения.

Comment: @ΝNL993, [files]: An array of File objects representing files to be shared. Мне нужно шарить файл, поэтому требуется поле file, а оно принимает в себя значения типа File. Или я что-то не так понимаю? (Понял, почему ты меня поправил. Исправил вопрос)